# LWC Radio Group

Tags: frontend, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, radio-group, lwc

I am trying to add 2 options in LWC as:

```
<template>
    <lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup"
                          label="Radio Group"
                          options={options}
                          value={value}
                          type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>
</template>
```

On selecting option 1 a LWC is invoked on selecting option 2 another LWC is invoked. However I am facing 2 issues here:
I want to make this selection mandatory and option 1 should display an info icon next to it, how can I achieve this?
To display:

```
* Select an option: (required)
Some description....
 1. Option 1 (info icon)
 2. Option 2
```